# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "With brains come senses, to detect whether the world is good or bad, and a memory."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> With brains come senses, to detect whether the world is good or bad,
>   and a memory.

Does it briefly mean "Brain, senses and memory come together ..."?

If so, is this grammatically correct?

Would you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> **With brains come senses, to detect whether the world is good or bad,
>   and a memory.** Together, these let the animal monitor in real time
>   whether things are getting better or worse. This in turn allows a
>   simple system of prediction and reward. Even animals with really
>   simple brains – insects, slugs or flatworms – can use their
>   experiences to predict what might be the best thing to do or eat next,
>   and have a system of reward that reinforces good choices.

https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn9951-top-10-lifes-greatest-inventions/#faq3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it briefly mean "Brain, senses and memory come together ..."?

No, it means

> There are two things that come with *brains*: (1) *senses* and (2) a *memory*.

The writer adds important information  to *senses*. The purpose of *senses* is

> to detect whether the world is good or bad.

That is just a nonrestrictive or nonessential clause. If you remove it, the sentence still makes sense and the meaning is unchanged.

> With brains come (1) senses and (2) a memory.

The sentence is grammatical. But I don't particularly like the use of "come" in it. It could be worded differently to make it easy to understand (e.g., *"Brains have two elements: senses and a memory"* or *"Brains come with senses and a memory"*). But that is a matter of style, I think.